# How to detect is a window of another process minimized or maximized?

Tags: c#, wpf

Currently I'm making a small gadget that made in WPF. It shows and hides according to another window's state.

So, let me name that another window be A. When A get shown or maximized, my gadget shows. When A minimized, my gadget hides.

So, how can I detect the change in state of a window of another process which is not in .NET? Btw sorry for my bad English :P

Comment: I dont think is possible in a easy manner.

Comment: sad but true in c#...

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378678/c-capture-windowstate-changes-of-another-application-wrote-in-c-c-i-think

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's only a part of the solution. If you know the title of the other window:

```
Process process = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.MainWindowTitle == "Title of window").SingleOrDefault();
if (process != null) {
      IntPtr wHnd = process.MainWindowHandle;
      Console.WriteLine("Minimized: "  + IsIconic(wHnd));
}
```

and:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to get the HWND from the process you want to reach.

[How to get main window handle from process id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888863/how-to-get-main-window-handle-from-process-id)

It requires loading win32 libraries in your C# WPF app like below.

[How can I use EnumWindows to find windows with a specific caption/title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867402/how-can-i-use-enumwindows-to-find-windows-with-a-specific-caption-title)

Once you have the HWND, you can check the visibility of the app by a combination of the WS_VISIBLE and WS_MAXIMIZE properties.

[How can I check if a window has WS_VISIBLE to set? (or if is visible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061246/how-can-i-check-if-a-window-has-ws-visible-to-set-or-if-is-visible)